# Django Queryset __in with None value in list

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-orm

```
a = M.objects.filter(f__in=[None, 1])
a.query.__str__()
u'SELECT * FROM "app_m" WHERE "app_m"."f" IN (None, 1)'
```

dont you think that would be `IN (NULL, 1)` ?

like:

```
a = M.objects.filter(f=None)
a.query.__str__()
u'SELECT * FROM "app_m" WHERE "app_m"."f" IS NULL'
```

Is this a default SQL behavior, django bug or I am missing something with `f__in=` ?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11):

```
a = M.objects.filter(Q(f__isnull=True) | Q(f__in=['1',...]))
```

Comment: this makes a query like this: WHERE ("app_m"."f" IN (1, 2) AND "app_m"."f" IS NULL)' this not includes (1, 2, NULL)

Comment: Don't forget to import `Q` as well: `from django.db.models import Q`

Comment: This doesn't work if your list doesn't contain None.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be and old bug in Django (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13768).

I just made few tests with Django 1.5 and it still is there: 'None' gets ignored when used in a list applied to "__in" (no errors).

Catherine approach works like a charm :)