# Django __in lookup doesn't look of None values

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Consider I have a model called Subject, and I want to filter the values based on the list of values. 
Consider the below list.

```
["John", "Brad", None]
```

When I try to filter out the result using __in lookup it doesn't look for None values. For example

```
Subject.objects.filter(user__in=["John", "Brad", None])
```

This will provide the queryset for John and Brad but not None. What I'm missing here? Can anyone please help me

Comment: In your model, has user field null=True attribute?

Comment: @kamilyrb Yes. It is a foreign key field and it has null=True attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Queryset \_\_in with None value in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365823/django-queryset-in-with-none-value-in-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NULL**s in DB (`None` in django) are not reqular values, so they need different approach:

```
Subject.objects.filter(Q(user__in=["John", "Brad", ]) | Q(user__isnull=True,))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try filtering like this

```
from django.db.models import Q

Subject.objects.filter(Q(user__in=["John", "Brad"]) | Q(user__isnull=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Q objects is better suited for this:

```py
Subject.objects.filter(Q(user__in=["John", "Brad"]) | Q(user__isnull=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Q objects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for `OR, AND and NOT` operations. Q objects provide you complete control over the where clause of the query.

Your queryset would be something like:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Subject.objects.filter(Q(user=None) | Q(user__in=["John", "Brad"]))
```

You can combine the Q objects in more complex ways to generate complex queries.